# Connecting to customer's stripe account

Tags: stripe-payments

Newbie to stripe here. I have seen this done on some apps but can't seem to be able to find documentation on stripe on how to do this:

On our website, we want to let our customers integrate our app with their Stripe account. So ideally I'd like to send the customers to stripe, they login and when they come back, our app has all the info we need from their stripe account (keys, ...?).

What is this flow called? Where can I find documentations for it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without knowing what you are planning on doing with your app it is difficult to know what you are exactly looking for. But I am guessing you’re looking for this guide right here: [Build a Stripe Extension](https://stripe.com/docs/building-extensions). If it doesn’t fit your use case, you may want to check out [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect).